# Discrepancy between the number of link clicks and referral numbers

Tags: google-analytics, reporting, google-tag-manager

I'm having a problem reconciling some figures in GA / GTM for two sites where I know the number of clicks from one to the other but the referral information doesn't seem to tally up I'm hoping someone can point me in the right direction/advise.

I have two sites:
a main corporate site (https://www.nhsnss.org) 
transactional service on a separate URL(https://prescription-tracker.nhsnss.scot.nhs.uk/ ).
I have analytics and GTM installed on both.  There is a link to the prescription tracker from a service start page on the main site (https://nhsnss.org/services/practitioner/pharmacy/prescriptions/prescription-tracker/)

I've got a tag/trigger (tracked as events) set up to look at the number of times a link is clicked from the main site to the service site based on the button class and as a double check since 27 May I've got a second tag/trigger looking at all outbound link (trigger - click url does not contain "nhsnss.scot") clicks to check if anyone has added any other links directly to the tracker elsewhere on the nhsnss.org.

Looking at the event figures from 28 May to 2 June they agree at 1863 total events or 1697 Unique events.  This to me shows that my tag/trigger setup in GTM is ok( apart from the double counting!)

Looking at the referral figures from nhsnss.org on the tracker for the same period I am getting the following figures on the home page of the tracker site (/):

Users: 1,555
Sessions: 3,243

Again I've tried to double-check these figures, this time by looking at the referral path which matches with the figures and the service start page on nhsnss.org ( /services/practitioner/pharmacy/prescriptions/prescription-tracker/)

Happy to be wrong on this but I'd have thought that a single link click from nhsnss.org to the tracker service would have started one session to be measured by analytics on the service.

Any advice/knowledge or solutions are gratefully received!

Many Thanks,
Robert

Answer (score 0):

You probably have double the amount of sessions because you might have both GA snippet and GTM snippet hardcoded on the website. That means that if you also have a GA Pageview tag served through GTM, GA will receive 2 pageviews for one user, one from the GA snippet hardcoded and one from the GA tag via GTM. Either pausing the GA pageview tag in GTM or removing the GA snippet from the website should fix your numbers.